# Different calendars or just one?

Tags: 2013, list, calendar, app, sharepoint-calendar

Suppose I need several Calendars for Meetings, Holidays, etc.

Do I need one Calendar App for each of them? Or do I just create one Calendar App and put there the different Calendars mentioned above (as an overlay)?

***Update:***

Where do these Calendars come from? Are those just regular Calendar Apps (Cal Overlay1, Cal Overlay2, Cal Overlay 3) added to only **one** Calendar App (Cal2)?

[image: Calendars]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the information is architected on your organization. Below is how I recently implemented similar requirement

1. On the root site I created Calendar App and named it Global Calendar.

   - On this Calendar I had all the company Holidays
2. Now each department has its own Calendar

   - This Calendar has team meetings for that particular department
3. Now you can add these department Calendar to the Global Calendar as an overlay